# Error select in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do a search query, but when I go to test it gives me an error.
I already tested to see if the query is working well!

```
 public Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsyncBy(String searchField){
        return database.Table<Employee>().Where(i => i.EmpName.Contains(searchField.ToLower())).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Query

```
 public class Employee {
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set;}

    internal bool Contains(string v) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Class Emplyee

```
    public async void OnTesteAsync() {
        var personItem1 = new Employee();
        personItem1.EmpName = searchBar_cliente.Text;
        await App.Database.SaveEmployeeAsync(personItem1);
    }

    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e){
        OnTesteAsync();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Mainclass

> SQLite.SQLiteException: no such function: tostring

This is the error that appears to me

Comment: You are throwing the NotImplementedException  in Handle_TextChanged that's why you are getting this error

Comment: you need to post complete code. it seems you updated the error you are getting now from not implemented to no such function. not sure. what you are trying!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, here is the updated code for anyone who has the same doubt.

It is an example of a search bar in the real-time search.

```
 public Task<List<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsyncBy(String searchField)
    {
        return database.Table<Employee>().Where(i => i.EmpName.ToLower().Contains(searchField.ToLower())).ToListAsync();
    }
```

That is the Select Query

```
 public class Employee
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }


}
```

Employee Class

```
 public async void OnTesteAsync()
    {

        lstView_cliente.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetEmployeesAsyncBy(searchBar_cliente.Text);

    }

    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnTesteAsync();

    }
```

MainClass

If you have any doubts, just say